# "And I you" with "you" as an indirect object

Tags: omissibility

If someone says, "I want to sit with you," is the response, "And I you," acceptable? I believe a better choice would be, "And I with you," but is "with" strictly necessary or does it just add clarity?

[An existing question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183171/can-a-person-say-and-i-you) covers the correctness of the general use of "And I you," but in those examples "you" is the direct object. If omission of the verb is acceptable, can the preposition be omitted as well?

Comment: As 'And I with you' is so formal as to be highfalutin, 'And I you' is not likely to be considered an acceptable deletion. It's pointless discussing the grammaticality or otherwise of things nobody says.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *It's pointless discussing the grammaticality or otherwise of things nobody says*  Wait.  Isn't that ELU's charter?

Comment: @deadrat It's usually the wordness of DIY candidate words that three people have decided they like.

Comment: *And I with you* sounds fine to me, but I certainly hear *So do I* more often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), the version without *with* is *not* grammatical.

Per chapter 15 "Coordination and supplementation", § 4.2 "Gapped coordination (*Kim is an engineer and Pat a barrister*)", p. 1338:

> One limitation is that the antecedent cannot end with a preposition or infinitival *to*, so that the underlined items cannot be omitted in [9] even though they appear in the first clause too:
>
> ```
> [9]   i  I went by car and Bill __ by bus.
>                                    --
>      ii  Kim was hoping to go to university and Pat __ to join the family business.
>                                                        --
> ```

(where the "antecedent" is the part that the gap refers back to; "went" in the first example, "was hoping" in the second).

Answer (score 0):

"And I with you" sounds very formal.

"And I you" also sounds very formal, and is probably incorrect. It would be correct if the original statement was something like "I love you" (without any proposition "with").

You could say "I want to sit with you too", or in colloquial American English the response could simply be "Me too".